# How can I prove the following logic equation?

Tags: boolean-algebra, algebraic-logic

I want to prove the following logic equation in logic algebra

$$ a \bar  b  \bar e f + \bar a \bar b ef+  ac \bar d \bar e + \bar a c \bar d e+ \bar b \bar c f + \bar b d f = ac \bar d \bar e + \bar a c \bar d e+ \bar b \bar c f + \bar b d f $$

Last 4 terms in the LHS are equal to the RHS. According to this fact I tried to show that

$$a \bar  b  \bar e f + \bar a \bar b ef = 0$$

But I couldn't do that. Is there a particular method to solve this kind of equation ( terms in RHS are in the LHS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts to show that $a\bar{b}\bar{e}f + \bar{a}\bar{b}ef = 0$ are vain since this is not true (take, for example, $a = f = 1, b = e = 0$). More generally, every non-trivial sum of products is not $0$, you just need to choose the values of variables properly to satisfy one particular summand.

To eliminate these summands you can use the absorption law $A + AB = A$. But since these summands are not absorbed by any other summand we need to add extra variables to them using the complementation law $A = aA + \bar{a}A$.

We have the following chains of transformations for each of the summands:
\begin{align}
a\bar{b}\bar{e}f = a\bar{b}c\bar{e}f + a\bar{b}\bar{c}\bar{e}f =  a\bar{b}cd\bar{e}f + a\bar{b}c\bar{d}\bar{e}f + a\bar{b}\bar{c}\bar{e}f.\\
\bar{a}\bar{b}ef = \bar{a}\bar{b}cef + \bar{a}\bar{b}\bar{c}ef =  \bar{a}\bar{b}cdef + \bar{a}\bar{b}c\bar{d}ef + \bar{a}\bar{b}\bar{c}ef.
\end{align}

Now observe that each of these six ($3 + 3$) summands is absorbed by one of the last four terms in the LHS of the original equation (for example, $a\bar{b}cd\bar{e}f$ is absorbed by $\bar{b}df$ and so on). So both $a\bar{b}\bar{e}f$ and $\bar{a}\bar{b}ef$ are absorbed producing that the LHS equals to the RHS.

Comment: Thank you very much! If we take the above equation as $A+B=A$, is it right to show that $AB=B$? Because if $B=AB$ that means the LHS of the main equation will be $ A+AB$. Then obviously, $ A+AB=A$.And in an equation like $CD=C$ can we show that $C+D=D$? In here also if $D=C+D$ then the LHS of the main equation will be $C(C+D)$. Which means $C(C+D)=C$.

Comment: @user303643: Well, technically yes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to simply omit terms from both sides which overlap remaining terms.

You can simplify both sides of the equation to

$$\bar b \bar c f + \bar b d f + \bar a c \bar d e + a c \bar d \bar e$$

Another way would be to write truth-tables or to list the minterms for both sides and compare the six-literal minterms.

There are more elaborate methods to compare complex functions. Ask your favorite search engine for `Equivalence Checking`.